# This item is unreachable because a previous item (item #1) is a more general match than this one

Tags: android

this error occures in android development "This item is unreachable because a previous item (item #1) is a more general match than this one".

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button1"></item>
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/buttonClick"></item>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/buttonSelect"></item>
</selector>
```

---

Comment: I know that selectors are very sensitive with their item order, maybe put the first default item to the last order. Then, it would be better to define even a pressed="false" and selected="false" statement.

Comment: make it one state_pressed="false"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> During each state change, the state list is traversed top to bottom
>   and the first item that matches the current state is used—the
>   selection is not based on the "best match," but simply the first item
>   that meets the minimum criteria of the state.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Your first item matches always, place it at the end instead

Answer (score 0):

You should change position same :

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/buttonSelect"></item>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/buttonClick"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button1"></item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button1"></item>
<item android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/buttonClick"></item>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/buttonSelect"></item>
</selector>
```